# Save each line of a .csv file as a separate .csv

Tags: linux, text-processing, csv

I have a `.csv` file with no headers and want to have each line saved as a separate `.csv` file with the new file name to be the value in column 2.

Comment: I have a nice answer for the first part. None for the other. And welcome!

Comment: Welcome. What have you tried this far? Also, we need to see the actual file (or a sample thereof).

Comment: Turns out the question (the solution) is pretty interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally i use awk command for this kind of task.

```
awk -F, '{print >$2".csv"}' input.csv
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, however turns out I need a tab (or space) delimited txt file but I can't seem to generate anything other than a comma-separated output. I have tried awk -F'\t' , -F'[t]' and a few other permutations of this but no files are generated an no error message (just a new prompt).